# Windows 10 desktops with different background images

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

Regarding the "multiple desktops" capability (image); is there a way to make each of the desktops have its own background image?

[image]

Comment: I use [Display Fusion](http://store.steampowered.com/app/227260/) for this. It's probably overkill if all you want is to have different backgrounds on each screen though.

Comment: I will look into it.  I was expecting there might be a registry hack or something.